# Can I use generics in this factory instead of AnyObject in Swift?

Tags: swift, generics

I am trying to store instances of a class that uses generics in a static variable in my factory for creating said instances. I have not been able to make the types correct on the factory for the instances variable. For the time being I've used `AnyObject` and force casted to the right implementation. It seems like there should be a better way to do this, but I can't figure out the correct syntax. I'd like to not use `AnyObject` and not force cast. Is this possible, and if so what do I need to do differently here?

Here is the code:

```swift
class StorageFactory {
  /// Instances of the storage, note the AnyObject here
  private static var instances: [String: AnyObject] = [:]

  private init() {}

  /// Create or return an existing shared storage instance
  static func create<Key: Hashable, Value>(name: String) -> Storage<Key, Value> {
    if let instance = instances[name] {
      // In order to make this work I have to force cast, but I don't want to
      // swiftlint:disable:next force_cast
      return instance as! Storage<Key, Value>
    }

    instances[name] = Storage<Key, Value>()

    return create(name: name)
  }
}

/// Class using generics
class Storage<Key, Value> where Key: Hashable {
  /// Dictionary for storing data
  private var data = [Key: Value]()

  /// Get an item from the storage by its key
  func get(forKey key: Key) -> Value? {
    return data[key]
  }

  /// Set an item from the storage by its key
  func set(_ value: Value, forKey key: Key) {
    data[key] = value
  }

  /// Get an item from the storage by its key, and when it does not exist provide a closure for setting it
  ///
  /// The closure is only called if the value does not already exist inside of the storage
  func getOrSet(forKey key: Key, setter: () -> Value?) -> Value? {
    if let value = get(forKey: key) {
      return value
    }

    if let newValue = setter() {
      set(newValue, forKey: key)
      return newValue
    }

    return nil
  }
}

// Used something like...

let date = Date()
let value = StorageFactory.create(name: "longDate").getOrSet(forKey: date) {
  date.formatted(date: .long, time: .omitted)
} ?? ""
```

Comment: Just a note, your `getOrSet` method in `Storage` should probably be `@autoclosure` for the `setter` parameter, since it's not always used and could be costly. Right now you always format a date even if not needed which is wasteful.

Comment: Unrelated but your getOrSet method could be condensed to `data[key] ?? setter()`

Comment: You are missing something else in your logic, there might already exist a Storage object for a given name but of a different type than the requested one. So you actually need to check this as well meaning force casting isn't really relevant any more. `guard let castInstance = instance as? Storage<Key, Value> else { <what do you do here?> }`

Comment: The way you build this correctly is to follow the pattern of SwiftUI's Environment, or Foundation's AttributeContainer. I started to write it up, but your interface doesn't make much sense, and I don't think it's what you mean. Do you really want named `[Key:Value]` containers, where Key and Value are fixed for each container? If you try to write a few more examples, I think that won't be what you want. What you probably want is a Key->(the correct type for this Key), and that's what Environment gives you. Study that. ("the correct value for this Key" could of course be a Dictionary.)